# Управление стилями по умолчанию Summernote

Tags: bootstrap

Редактор [Summernote](https://summernote.org/) по умолчанию включает режим "жирный" при фокусе на пустом окне редактора:

[image]
<sub>(источник: [scaleengine.net](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/37aaf3fa79d729e31b17505fbe2affbe.png))</sub>

Что нужно сделать, чтобы отменить это поведение? Я не нашел явных настроек конфигурации, очевидно, он эту информацию откуда-то берет, но даже подмена `document.queryCommandState` не помогла. Система целиком висит на опенкарте, который сам по себе кхм-кхм как в части исполнения, так и документации, поэтому проблему сложно оттрейсить.

Summernote вызывается самым обычным способом:

```
$('textarea').summernote();
```

Comment: Минимального фиддла не будет?

Comment: @Nofate Добавил, но он реально минимальный.

Comment: Лучшая документация - код, угу. Найти код, который выполняется по нажатию этой кнопки, прописать `debugger;` в этой функции, обновить страницу, проанализировать call stack.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, я пробовал раскручивать (не через клик-хендлер, правда), и уперся в некоторое количество методов, работу которых не понимаю и не хотел бы тратить время на них (`document.queryCommandState`, например).

Comment: А подробнее можно? Скачал [архив](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/archive/master.zip) с главной, открыл пример из `/examples/textarea.html`, убрал в примере текст из `textarea` и открыл файл в браузере - никакого жирного выделения нет. Добавил в `textarea` строку `<p><b></b></p>` - никакого выделения нет, добавил `<p><b>&nbsp;</b></p>` - выделение появилось. Может быть у вас содержимое не пустое? Попробуйте воспроизвести [на этом](http://jsfiddle.net/3mwpcfme/) (можно через встроенный редактор, но у меня коммент, поэтому только fiddle)

Comment: @Etki, summernote поставляется в виде плагена|из коробки для CMS OpenCart?

Comment: @romeo примерно так. Там нет такого понятия, как плагин, он просто есть внутри, никаких вызовов с заданием ему поведения по умолчанию я не нашел.

Comment: @BOPOH чуть позже посмотрю, но уверен, что у меня там пустота. Насколько понял, он действительно включает/выключает стили по css, но все, чего я смог добитьсся комментированием найденных строчек - кнопка отключалась, а жирный текст оставался.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на страничку где можно наблюдать поведение

Comment: @ReinRaus конечно же, во время создания тестового примера оказалось, что целевой элемент лежит внутри `label`, а у `label` есть правило `font-weight:bold`, а summernote просто подтягивает стили содержимого. Можете написать ответ о том, что проблема обязательно найдется в процессе создания тестового примера, я его приму.

Comment: @Etki, сделайте это сами, пожалуйста, если не трудно. Ведь Вы сами разобрались в проблеме. А я Вам плюсик поставлю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема оказалась тривиальной: у Summernote нет конфигурации включенных стилей по умолчанию (во всяком случае, я ничего такого не обнаружил), однако он подтягивает стили того элемента, на котором установлен курсор. Textarea (равно как и заменивший ее элемент summernote) лежала внутри label, к которому применялось правило `font-weight: bold`, на который и срабатывал Summernote. Простого

```
label * {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

хватило для решения проблемы.

Спасибо @ReinRaus за подталкивание меня в нужном направлении.

Comment: Что-то у вас решение оказалось страшнее проблемы :) `<label>` же не просто так жирным делался, а вы взяли и поломали дизайн всех форм на сайте. Лучше вынесите `<textarea>` за пределы тэга `<label>`, чтобы стили не применялись там, где не надо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Там очень все плохо в проекте, проще было докинуть правило, чем разгребать верстку.

Comment: Сделайте тогда отдельное правило именно для `Summernote`. А то в проекте стенает только хуже. К примеру, `label .summernote` подойдет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov оно через style инжектится только на этой странице. Ну и немного в другом виде, я не помню, какие конкретно элементы там перечислены.